# Symfony doctrine error "DoctrineMigrationsBundle requires DoctrineBundle to be enabled."

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have created a fresh Symfony project and I keep getting this "DoctrineMigrationsBundle requires DoctrineBundle to be enabled." error and cant get rid of it. Apparently I'm the only one on the planet who gets this error as google wasn't too helpful.

in the config/bundles.php file I have the following which should "Enable" DoctrineBundle but I'm missing something and cant tell what it is.

```
return [
    Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\FrameworkBundle::class => ['all' => true],
    Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\DoctrineBundle::class => ['all' => true],
    Doctrine\Bundle\MigrationsBundle\DoctrineMigrationsBundle::class => ['all' => true],
];
```

Comment: I just ran 'symfony new test' followed by 'composer require orm-pack', got the same bundles.php as you did and it all seems to work okay.  How did you create your project and what specifically is triggering the error for you?

Comment: Same as you only difference composer require doctrine, nothing else special, i have also deleted the project a few times, re-created it and the same error persists

Comment: Try again using the orm-pack.  If you still have trouble then check your code into a public repo.

Comment: The solution was :  Took the skeleton of a an older working symfony 5 project and built on that after removing a few snippets of unnecessary code. Something must be wrong somewhere in my environment but time does not allow me to investigate for a better solution. Thank you !

Comment: I had the same error and in my case it was a missing `config/packages/doctrine.yml` configuration file.

Answer (score 1):

It needs the file `config/packages/doctrine.yaml`, containing at least:

```yaml
doctrine:
  dbal:
```

Then the error disappeard.

For the rest of configuration see the [Configuration Reference](https://symfony.com/bundles/DoctrineBundle/current/configuration.html).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error,
for some reason, the yaml files that should be inside `config/packages` were not committed to git.

You can do the following:

- create a new symfony project
- copy the config/packages folder from the fresh install to my project
- copy the `/bin` folder as well if it is also missing
- add these 2 line to .gitignore

```
    !/bin/
    !/config/packages/*
```

[image: File tree including config/packages]

(Adding the `!/bin` to `.gitignore` is not related to this error, but it should not be ignored anymore as of symfony 6 and is the solution to fix this other error: `Script cache:clear returned with error code 1`
`Could not open input file: ./bin/console).` when you install a symfony project from git.

[image: Error solved by adding !/bin to .gitignore]